# How to publish an Object message via jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jms, activemq-classic

Jmeter JMS publisher has an option to select the Message Type as `Object Message` and there is text area saying `Text Message or Object Message serialized to XML by XStream`.

But I couldn't send a Object message to the Message Broker

If I simple enter an XML in the text area and select the message type as Object Message (Obviously this is wrong :) ). I am getting the following exception

```
jmeter.protocol.jms.sampler.PublisherSampler: hello com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.CannotResolveClassException: hello
at com.thoughtworks.xstream.mapper.DefaultMapper.realClass(DefaultMapper.java:79)
```

How can I send a simple Object message via Jmeter

Answer (score 0):

These tutorials might be useful;

http://wso2.com/library/tutorials/2013/08/how-to-use-apache-jmeter-to-publishsubscribe-to-jms-queuestopics-in-wso2-message-broker/

http://aparnaank.blogspot.nl/2013/06/how-to-use-jmeter-jms-publisher.html

Comment: Thanks. but both are having how to publish text message, not object message :(